# Run a multiline bash script piped from stdin

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting, pipe, stdin

I'm looking for a simple way to include multi-line scripts inline in documentation to make it transparent what each step does.

This works

```
echo "echo 1234" | bash
```

So does this

```
echo 'for N in 1 2 3; do echo $N; done' | bash
```

However, I'd like to use something like this (which does not work):

```
echo <<EOF | bash
for N in 1 2 3; do
echo "N is ${N}"
done
EOF
```

**Update**, the closest working solution so far is:

```
cat <<EOF|bash
for N in 1 2 3 4; do
    echo "N is now \$N"
done
EOF
```

Ideally though I'd like to not have to escape the `\$N`

A correct solution will not:

- use tools not installed default debian config
- involve a temp file
- downloaded the script ( `curl -o - htpp://blah.com/script | bash` etc )

Ideally it's something something the reader can copy paste, press enter, and will execute without further action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you quote or escape the here-document delimiter (i.e. `<<'EOF'` or `<<\EOF`instead of just `<<EOF`), the shell won't do expansions (of variables etc) on the content.

```
cat <<'EOF' | bash
for N in 1 2 3; do
echo "N is ${N}"
done
EOF
```

BTW, the `cat` command isn't really doing anything useful here (it's what's known as a ["useless use of cat", or UUoC)](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). You can eliminate it and send input directly to `bash`:

```
bash <<'EOF'
for N in 1 2 3; do
echo "N is ${N}"
done
EOF
```

If the snippet needs to read input, that's a little tricky because the script's input is... the script snippet itself. On most unix-like OSes, you can avoid this by passing the script over a different file descriptor, and telling `bash` to "execute" that file descriptor:

```
bash /dev/fd/3 3<<'EOF'
read -p "Enter something here: " input
echo "You entered: ${input}"
EOF
```

But note that any variables set in one of these snippets (like `$input` here) are only set in that one shell process, and will be lost when it exits.

Comment: fantastic answer TIL alot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is something like this:

```
bash -c '
    echo "Simple scriptlike thingy"
    for I in 1 2 3 45; do
      echo "I is now ${I}"
    done
'
```

Note that this essentially gives the while script as a parameter to the `-c` switch, and this parameter itself will be parsed by `bash`. This is why you can't use `"` signs like this:

```
bash -c "
    THING=text
    echo this will not work: $THING
"
```

because in the parameter, `$THING` is substituted before passed as argument, and since `THING` is unset, it will be replaced to an empty string. A string enclosed in apostrophes is not parsed, so it can be used to contain variables to be set when the "second bash process" parses the script.

For more complex scripts, I think the best way would be to ask your readers to save the script and run it, but for simple constructs, the above should work.

Comment: thanks for the answer, `bash -c 'blah'` will work for 90% of my needs, I'm going to hold out for a while for an answer which allows both " and ' -- just in case